# Using Byte Buddy for Java Agent

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I wish to create an agent to attach to our live Tomcat & Weblogic servers which will intercept all method calls to all classes declared in my companies package and do some logging of metrics such as execution time.

I came across the Byte Buddy library which seems to cater for this. However, I am not 100% clear on the approach to creating an agent using Byte Buddy:

- The following article suggests that one creates an own agent and makes no mention of the `byte-buddy-agent`: http://mydailyjava.blogspot.ie/2015/01/make-agents-not-frameworks.html
- However, I do see someone has created his/her own `byte-buddy-agent` so I am
  not sure if I am meant to use this.
  https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/tree/master/byte-buddy-agent

I went with the approach of creating my own agent and packaged it up using Maven to include Byte Buddy as a *fat jar* (so that the Byte Buddy code is on the class path) which I reference from my `catalina.bat`.

***Edit: I have since downloaded the source and figured out that the AgentBuilder relies on the byte-buddy-agent package so the above question is irrelevant.***

Tomcat starts up fine and I can see that the agent is called as I see the "Entered premain" `System.out`.

However I never see the "Intercepted" `System.out` when I execute the code on a separate war file deployed to Tomcat.
***Edit: Code below updated based on Rafael's response and this is now working.***

Can somebody tell me what I might be doing wrong here? I've included the agent code below.

Also, can someone tell me which `ElementMatchers` is best for package matching? I tried `nameStartsWith` but it had no effect and the API documentation does not state if it is the fully qualified class name.

***Edit: The nameStartsWith does check the package. ***

Anyway, thanks in advance for any help!

```
package com.mycompany.agent;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;

public class MyAgent {

public static void premain(String agentArgument, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    System.out.println("Entered premain");
    try{
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .withListener( new AgentBuilder.Listener() {

                    public void onComplete(String arg0) {
                        System.out.println("Completed - " + arg0);
                    }

                    public void onError(String arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                        System.out.println("Error - " + arg0+", "+arg1.getMessage());
                        arg1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    public void onIgnored(String arg0) {
                        System.out.println("Ignored - " + arg0);
                    }

                    public void onTransformation(TypeDescription arg0, DynamicType arg1) {
                        System.out.println("Transformed - " + arg0+", type = "+arg1);
                    }

                })
                .rebase(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("com.mycompany"))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                    public DynamicType.Builder transform(DynamicType.Builder builder, TypeDescription typeDescription) {
                        return builder.method(ElementMatchers.any()).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new Interceptor()));
                    }
                }).installOn(instrumentation);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception instrumenting code : "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



package com.mycompany.agent;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class Interceptor {

@RuntimeType
public Object intercept( @SuperCall Callable<?> callable, @AllArguments Object[] allArguments, @Origin Method method, @Origin Class clazz) throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object response;
    try{
        response = callable.call();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred in method call: " + methodName(clazz, method, allArguments) + " Exception = " + e);
        throw e;
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Method " + methodName(clazz, method) + " completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " miliseconds");
    }
    return response;
}

private String methodName(Class clazz, Method method){
    return methodName(clazz, method, null);
}

private String methodName(Class clazz, Method method, Object[] allArguments){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(clazz.getName());
    builder.append(".");
    builder.append(method.getName());
    builder.append("(");
    for(int i = 0; i < method.getParameters().length; i++) {

        builder.append(method.getParameters()[i].getName());
        if(allArguments != null) {
            Object arg = allArguments[i];
            builder.append("=");
            builder.append(arg != null ? arg.toString() : "null");              
        }

        if(i < method.getParameters().length - 1) {
            builder.append(", ");
        }
    }
    builder.append(")");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Everything seems to be right. You should always try registering an `AgentBuider.Listener` which will expose stack traces of unsuccessful instrumentations if Byte Buddy causes an exception for signaling an illegal instrumentation attempt.

I assume that your class's package-private definition of your `Interceptor` is the cause of this exception. Your interceptor must be visible to all instrumented code. Otherwise, the class is not invokable.

Comment: One other thing, I would like to get access to more details about the method such as the name and the arguments. I do see the AllArguments and Origin annotations but adding these causes the interceptor method not to fire. Can you tell me how these should be used?

Comment: Can you edit your question to display the new interceptor?

Comment: The onError of the listener informs me that the issue is with the Origin annotation: "The net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.commons.Method arg2 method's 2 parameter is annotated with a Origin annotation with an argument not representing a Class, Method, String, int, MethodType or MethodHandle type"

Comment: This works fine if I only use the SuperCall and AllArguments annotations.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I mistakenly set the parameter type for the Origin to be net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.commons.Method when it should be java.lang.reflect.Method. I will edit the source to reflect. Thanks

Comment: You should always register an AgentBuilder.Listener if you do not know what is happening. But good that you figured it out.